# Newbie, not sure how to save the location of a draggable item in HTML within a Rails app using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui

First, I've googled and searched and read questions here on SO for hours, and am at my wits end...
I'm a Rails newbie (and pretty much new at all this), working on a task manager site as a project. I am trying to make a list of projects, in the projects/index.html.erb view, be able to be dragged around to a different position, and then be saved in that spot. So far I have figured out, using jQuery, how to make the project items draggable, and thats's great. But upon refreshing the page, it's back to the original list order. I made a gist of the files in question, which I will post below. Also, I found an answer to a similar question on here, but I don't have any familiarity with AJAX...I have this code in my project.js now, but I do not know what to do for the "put your AJAX call here" part (you can see it in my gist)...or if that is even the right thing to do. Any help on this, I would greatly appreciate it!!

https://gist.github.com/vtboyarc/a4d59c4dabce958f3788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `projects.js` file:

```
$("#myList").sortable({
  stop: function(event, ui){        
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post', // this is your HTTP request type (typically POST if you want to write something)
      url: 'url_for_your_controller_action_to_receive_ajax_request',
      data: { 'data_key_you_want_to_pass_to_controller' : the_data_value },
      success: function(msg) {
        // msg is the value of the response from your controller action
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I would read up on [the Rails guides on AJAX](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) for more info.